# Amfphp error with new PHP version

Tags: php, apache-flex, amfphp

I hope somebody may faced this issue.I searched through google regarding this and I found few options of how to fix.But that didnt help me.So I posted here.

In my previous server we are using the fedora 5.2.5 version of PHP.But in my current server we are using REDHAT with PHP 5.3 with amfphp version 1.4.In old one we are not getting any issues.But with Redhat I am getting the following error.

```
(mx.rpc::Fault)#0
errorID = 0
faultCode = "Client.Error.MessageSend"
faultDetail = "Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.BadVersion: "
faultString = "Send failed"
message = "faultCode:Client.Error.MessageSend faultString:'Send failed' faultDetail:'Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.BadVersion: '"
name = "Error"
rootCause = (Object)#1
code = "NetConnection.Call.BadVersion"
description = ""
details = ""
level = "error"
```

Do you have any idea on this.How can I fix this issue.Please let me know if you have any idea on this.

reference site I followed:
1) http://sourceforge.net/projects/amfphp/forums/forum/247252/topic/3941969
2) http://www.gotoandlearnforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=20525

Comment: I can confirm that amfphp 1.4 does work with PHP 5.3.  All is not lost!  :)  Not sure what would cause a sendfail but off the bat i'd compare notes from the 5.2.5 plugins and 5.3 plugins, see if any modules were forgotten.

Comment: @MattH.Yes.I also got working now with this new version.Few thinks I did in the amfphp and I put the details below as my answer.So it will help some one.

Comment: for me `NetConnection.Call.BadVersion` mostly occurred due to some database query error, but I strongly think that it is raised due to php fatal errors

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for everyone those who are viewed my question to answer.Now I fixed the issue after played little bit with charles tool explain in [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/amfphp/forums/forum/247252/topic/3941969) link.

**Error 1:**

Whats the issue I got, is explain [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/php-it-is-not-safe-to-rely-on-the-systems-timezone-settings) link i.e.

```
t is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function.
```

So put the line

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
```

in gateway.php

Also I added the line

```
error_reporting(0); below $gateway->setErrorHandling(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Because we are in live.But not sure it will help or not. If I am wrong please let me know.

**Error 2:**

The second one I got the issue explained in [this](http://creative-geeks.com/blog/2009/12/11/amfphp-and-php-5-3-bugfix/) link.i.e

```
function eregi_replace is depreciated.
```

So I go with the solution they posted in the above link.replaced the amfphp/core/shared/util/MethodTable.php file with the suggestion in the above link.

Hope this will help in some one. :)